# how code a function similar to itertools.product in python 2.5

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples, e.g:

```
A=[(1,2,3), (3,5,7,9), (7)]
```

and want to generate all permutations with one item from each tuple.

```
1,3,7
1,5,7
1,7,7
...
3,9,7
```

I can have any number of tuples and a tuple can have any number of elements.
And I can't use `itertools.product()` because python 2.5.

Comment: Note that you will need to redefine your A. When you say
`A=[(1,2,3),(3,5,7,9),(7)]` the `(7)` at the end is evaluated as an integer, not a tuple. Therefore it's not iterable, and `product(*A)` will throw a TypeError. If you say
`A=(1,2,3),(3,5,7,9),(7,)]` then `product(*A)` will work.

Comment: Ok, I see, but this was a too simple example. I have A as a list of lists of 3-number tuples. But I want to remove the outer list and get A = lists of 3-number tuples. How do I do that? Better to make this a new beginner python question i think.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

docs of [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) have an example of how to implement it in py2.5:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Comment: fixed that, I've accidentally copied the example from py3.1 docs.

Answer (score 9):

```
def product(*iterables):
    """ Equivalent of itertools.product for versions < 2.6,
        which does NOT build intermediate results.
        Omitted 'repeat' option.
        product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    """
    nIters = len(iterables)
    lstLenths = []
    lstRemaining = [1]
    for i in xrange(nIters-1,-1,-1):
        m = len(iterables[i])
        lstLenths.insert(0, m)
        lstRemaining.insert(0, m * lstRemaining[0])
    nProducts = lstRemaining.pop(0)

    for p in xrange(nProducts):
        lstVals = []

        for i in xrange(nIters):
            j = p/lstRemaining[i]%lstLenths[i]
            lstVals.append(iterables[i][j])
        yield tuple(lstVals)
```

Answer (score 5):

When playing around with generators, I too found a version of `itertools.product`, and it is almost as fast as the (native) library version, while being 100% compatible with it, and it does not build intermediate results:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    "Alternative fast implementation of product for python < 2.6"
    def cycle(values, uplevel):
        for prefix in uplevel:       # cycle through all upper levels
            for current in values:   # restart iteration of current level
                yield prefix + (current,)

    stack = (),             
    for level in tuple(map(tuple, args)) * kwds.get('repeat', 1):
        stack = cycle(level, stack)  # build stack of iterators
    return stack
```

With python 2.7.3, I found the performance to be really good (usually only about a factor of 5-10 slower with essentially the same memory usage).

```
>>> import itertools as itt
>>> timeit for _ in itt.product(range(20), range(3), range(150)): pass
1000 loops, best of 3: 221 µs per loop
>>> timeit for _ in product(range(20), range(3), range(150)): pass
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.14 ms per loop
```

**EDIT**: made code even simpler and Python 3-ready.

Comment: Using a try/except to end a loop isn't great. You're basically relying on an error to short circuit your loop.

Comment: I disagree with the accusation that I am abusing "error" conditions to exit the loop -- `StopIteration` is a valid condition to check for in a looping construct since it is internally used whenever a loop is terminated. Note that exceptions and `StopIteration` in particular have a slightly wider use in Python than in C++, cf. also the Zen of Python.

Answer (score 4):

The itertools documentation contains full code showing what each function is equivalent to. The `product` implementation is [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: Thanks, I was to fast to ask I think.