# Kotlin: Iterate through every pair (or generally fixed-sized subsets) in collection

Tags: kotlin, iterator, set, subset, pairwise

Is there a short/idiomatic way to iterate through every pair of elements in a collection?

Even better would be a method that iterates through all fixed-cardinality subsets of a collection.

The classic and ugly approach would be:

```
val s = setOf(1, 2, 3, 4)

for (i in s) {
    for (j in s) {
        if (i != j) {
            println("$i $j")
        }
    }
}
```

For having bigger subsets, more loops are necessary, so this isn't scalable.

Comment: Not sure you can do much better than that. Keep in mind that the `if` condition `i != j` might work for sets but it will produce possibly odd results for lists. If you have `listOf(1,1,1,1,1)` that loop won't do anything. It might be what you want, but I don't know.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53749357/idiomatic-way-to-create-n-ary-cartesian-product-combinations-of-several-sets-of)?

Comment: Cartesian products and subsets are similar, but different. So I guess sadly not @Lino

Comment: I think the technical term here is [2-permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n).

Comment: Check out this https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/split-list-into-parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got already the most idiomatic way to solve it. If you want to do it more functional, this is what you can convert it to:

```kotlin
s.map { i -> s.map { i to it } }
    .flatten()
    .filter { (left, right) -> left != right }
    .onEach { (i, j) -> println("$i $j") }
```

Comment: `flatMap` would be better than `map{}/flatten()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is technically also *O(n^2)* but will have a little less than half as many iterations: `(n^2 - n) / 2`

```
val l = s.toList()
for (i in s.indices) {
    for (j in i + 1 until s.size) {
        println("${l[i]}, ${l[j]}")
        println("${l[j]}, ${l[i]}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find an implementation of the power set operation, you can take all elements of the power set with length = 2.

Comment: Yes, thats true. But for a set of size n the powerset has size 2^n. This runtime is horrible. The number of pairs for example is only n^2 asymptotically.