# Generate numbers that meet criteria in Python

Tags: python, pandas

The below code takes 2 seconds to finish.
The code looks clean but is very inefficient.

I am trying to pre-generate the ways you can build up to a total of `max_units` in increments of 2.

I'd then filter the created table to where `secondary_categories` meet certain criteria:

- 'A' is >10% of the total and 'B'<=50% of the total.

Do you see a better way to get the combinations in increments of 2 that meet criteria like the above?

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

primary_types= ['I','II']                
secondary_categories= ['A','B'] 

unitcategories= len(primary_types)*len(secondary_categories) #up to 8

min_units= 108; max_units= 110 #between 20 and 400
max_of_one_type= max_units


args =[[i for i in range(2,max_of_one_type, 2)] for x in range(unitcategories)]

lista= list(itertools.product(*args))

filt= [True if max_units>=l>=min_units else False for l in list(map(sum, lista))]

lista= list(itertools.compress(lista, filt))

df=pd.DataFrame(lista, columns= pd.MultiIndex.from_product([primary_types, secondary_categories], names=['', '']))

df['Total']=df.sum(axis=1)

df
```

Extending the following makes it take significantly longer or run out of memory: `primary_types, secondary_categories, min_units, max_units`.

Thank you

Comment: I would *start* by not needlessly calling `list` on every iterator in your code, thereby defeating the *purpose* of using iterators...

Comment: It seems to me you can leave out the intermediate `filt` list and dispense with using `itertools.compress` and just filter in a list comprehension...

Comment: Note also, args *can just be `[range(2, max_of_one_type, 2)] for x in range(unitcategories)]`.... why doy ou needlessly make lists out of everything? like, specifically `[i for i in range(2,max_of_one_type, 2)]`, anything of the form `[i for i in whatever]` can just be `list(whatever)`, but in this case, **there is no point in converting your `range` object into a lsit to begin with...**

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any insight about the problem of generating too much data for the available memory?

Comment: Do you have to work in increments of 2? Everything throughout the entire algorithm is an even number so you can get an easy win by dividing everything by 2 at the start. Then, when it's all done, multiply the result you want by 2.

Comment: It's actually a really cool problem. I like it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

OK so I'm posting this just FYI but I don't think it's an ideal solution. I believe there exists a far more elegant solution and I bet it involves `numpy`. However, this should at least be faster than the OP:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd


primary_types = ["I", "II"]
secondary_categories = ["A", "B"]

unitcategories = len(primary_types) * len(secondary_categories)  # up to 8

min_units = 54
max_units = 55  # between 10 and 200
max_of_one_type = max_units

args = [range(1, max_of_one_type) for x in range(unitcategories)]

lista = [x for x in itertools.product(*args)if max_units >= sum(x) >= min_units]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    lista,
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [primary_types, secondary_categories], names=["", ""]
    ),
)

df["Total"] = df.sum(axis=1)

df = df * 2  # multiply by 2 to get the result you want
```

1. I divided everything by 2 at the start and multiplied the result at the end by 2.
2. I removed all unnecessary uses of `list`
3. I removed the `itertools.compress` and `filt`  and instead just put an `if` in the list comprehension (where `lista` is declared and assigned)

Comment: Thank you. Your solution cut the processing time in half. But if I extend the secondary_categories by adding an element "C"  like  ["A", "B", "C"], the main problem I'm having become much more apparent - the code doesn't finish

Comment: Yes, I imagine that would be the case. I would need more time to work on this problem in an abstract way. There is a pattern to the tuples whose sums are within the specified range and I'm certain there exists a numpy function that would do the job perfectly. I cannot look at this any more now but I will revisit it again in the near future. Good luck, fellow coder! :)

Comment: @Kdog yes, because your algorithm is polynomial time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Could have been worse right? Could have been exponential. I have a feeling I'll end up converting the code to loops and distributing over multiple cores to generate the options that add up to the total at the increments of 2. Unfortunately a formulaic solution would give continuous values.

Comment: @Kdog Parallelizing isn't really going to help the polynomial time... But it may be just enough for what you are trying to do

Comment: @PeacefulJames Just as an FYI, this here looks really interesting 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166794/tree-to-find-all-cartesian-product-of-lists-whose-product-is-greater-than-a-thre