# Finction with nested loop and kwargs: how to invoke two lists one after another? (Cartesian product)

Tags: python, variadic-functions, keyword-argument

I'm trying to recreate `itertools.product`.

I know how to create a loop for this task, ex.:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [5, 6, 7]
arr_out = []

for i in arr1:
    for i1 in arr2:
        final = i, i1
        arr_out.append(final)
print(arr_out)
```

output:

`[(1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7)]`

But I wonder how to create a function from that with `kwargs`.
I try something like this:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [5, 6, 7]

def my_cool_product(**kwargs):
    
    arr_out = []
    
    for i in kwargs[0].items():
        for i1 in kwargs[1].items():
            final = i, i1
            arr_out.append(final)

print(my_cool_product(arr1, arr2))
```

But it doesn't work.

output:

`TypeError: my_cool_product() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`

I don't know how to call each subsequent `kwarg` in a nested loop.
I want to get the same output as in the first example.

**The goal is to do it without importing any modules, like `itertools`, in other words, do it from scratch.**

Comment: There's plenty of solutions in there including using `*args`.

Comment: Have you looked at the answers?

Comment: Yes, you were right, there is a solution with factors I needed(first post). I would like to know - anyway - why I got an error output. What's wrong with `**kwargs`?

Comment: How to fish is more important than [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs) [fish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) :-) Searching well will help you a lot big time, otherwise you'll be waiting for other people to answer which will take you considerably longer each time.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution related to my question: with `**kwargs`. I haven't seen any similar case on the web ( for python 3.x). Just with `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**kwargs` is unfit for a function like the one you're proposing.

As linked from in the comments, `**kwargs` is used for [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#In_Python) keyword argument functions. In your case you're looking for any number of unnamed lists.

Let's say there's only 2 arrays you're trying to get the product of, as you imply in your example function:

```
def my_cool_product(**kwargs): 
    arr_out = []
    for i in kwargs["array1"]:
        for i1 in kwargs["array2"]:
            final = i, i1
            arr_out.append(final)
    return arr_out
```

You may then use it like so:

```
>>> my_cool_product(array1=[1,2,3], array2=[4,5,6])
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

But since the names `array1` and `array2` are meaningless, using `*args` would be preferred:

```
def my_cool_product(*args): 
    arr_out = []
    for i in args[0]:
        for i1 in args[1]:
            final = i, i1
            arr_out.append(final)
    return arr_out

>>> my_cool_product([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

For further supporting any number of lists, please see the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681269/how-code-a-function-similar-to-itertools-product-in-python-2-5) questions, so as for the [difference between `*args` and `**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters).

Comment: Thank you, now I understand why I could find a good solution with `**kwargs`. I was looking at it from the wrong angle.